# Drupal 7 form submission in modal dialogs

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, drupal-7

I have embedded a view in a commerce product form which displays links to any product display nodes that reference the product. There is also an 'edit' link which loads the product display edit form in a jQuery modal dialog (a dialog window is created from an empty div in the product form, then the entire node edit page is loaded into it).

I would like to be able to display the result of the form submission in the same dialog, instead of it replacing the entire page. The Media and Views modules do something similar, but I am struggling to identify how exactly. Can someone please outline the necessary steps to achieve this?

Comment: copy/paste the code which do the thing you have explained and your result of the form submission is your custom form ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial to handle webforms in ctools modal window: http://drupal.org/node/1196150. It works fine: both the webform and the confirmation message will be displayed in the modal window without page reloading.

The [Ctools auto-modal](http://drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal) module might also be a solution (though I struggled to make it works with webform)